# Modify multiple accounts script

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, scripting

I need a script to make modifications on multiple accounts.
Within the account, in general info, the display name should include “name +surname” + ***Custom Title***.
So the script should just add the ***Custom Title*** to their existing Name.
I have a Domain Controller running windows 2008 R2 Standard. There is a domain.com,  the users are in a specific OU, all the accounts I need modified start with tdy+name+adm.
Can anyone help?

Comment: You say you only need to add custom title to end up with name +surname” + Custom Title, but then say they currently have tdy+name+adm. So if you just add Custom title it will be tdy+name+adm+custom title. Which is it? prehaps an example with some names and expected result would be more helpful

Comment: In addition to clarifying what changes you want per account vs. what accounts you want changed, can you also include what you've already tried?

Comment: let me clarify: the samaccount name is tdytudoradm the display name is Tudor Lucian. I need to add to the display name a custom title like this: Tudor Lucian AD admin. I haven't tried anything yet.

Answer (score 0):

Import-module activedirectory

foreach ($user in (get-aduser -filter {samaccountname -like "tdy*"}-searchbase "ou=Accounts,dc=test,dc=com")) {
$displN = $user.Name
write-host $displN
$displN=$displN + " AD Admin"
write-host $displN
$sam=$user.samaccountname
set-aduser -identity $sam -displayname $displN
      }

I solved my problem. If anyone needs it.